# How to conditionally assign variable value in template of play framework 2.0?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I want to create a variable called style and assign its value 
based on the value of the input parameter @filter

I read the play's documentation, but the current solution I can get 
it works is something like: which the list template part is duplicated...

```
@(filter: String = "error")(body: (String) => Html)

@filter match {

  case "HOT" => {
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="icon-hot">this is a list item..</li>
      <li class="icon-hot">this is a list item..</li>
    </ul>   
  }

  case "NEW" => {
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="icon-new">this is a list item..</li>
      <li class="icon-new">this is a list item..</li>
    </ul>   
  }

}
```

How do I assign "icon-new" & "icon-hot" to a variable @style and use it latter when writing the list template like this?

```
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="@style">this is a list item..</li>
      <li class="@style">this is a list item..</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

in style.scala.html

```
@(filter: String = "error")(body: (String) => Html)

@filter match {    
  case "OPEN" => {
      @body("icon-plus")
  }
  case "FOLLOWING" => {
      @body("icon-comments")
  }
  case "HOT" => {
      @body("icon-fire")
  } 
}
```

And in list template

```
@(filter: String = "HOT")

@style(filter) { style =>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="@style">this is a list item..</li>
    <li class="@style">this is a list item..</li>
  </ul>   
}
```

but I'm still not very clear how this works...especially the following part:

```
(body: (String) => Html)

@body("icon-plus")
```

Comment: Play 2.0 templates are just functions which accept parameters and return HTML. So, body is a function that takes a string parameter and returns HTML.